# If it is any kind of bug from firefox or Ubuntu 20.04 side?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, firefox

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm quite new to Linux OS as well. I don't know whether it is a bug or not. After logging off my system(Windows+l) and logging back in, I was not able to view the Firefox browser the way it was before logging off. If this issue haven't been raised yet, hopefully one of you who views my question will be able to raise an incident.

[Image before logging off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xClgr.png)

[Image after logging back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFS1N.png)

In the image(after logging back) you can see that changing the tabs functionality on Firefox is covered with the bar that have Activities on the top left(I don't know what exactly it is called).
Because of this:

1. I have to restart the browser again to get the complete view of the browser.
2. I won't be able to change tabs after logging back to the system

Comment: What difference exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the image(after logging back) you can see that changing the tabs functionality on Firefox is covered with the  bar that have Activities on the top left(I don't know what exactly it is called).
Because of this:
1. I have to restart the browser again to get the complete view of the browser.
2. I won't be able to change tabs after logging back to the system

Comment: What happens if you maximize the window after logging back in?

Comment: I have been trying to replicate the same bug multiple times, it is getting replicated only a few times when I log-back. The maximize and minimize options aren't visible right, when I log-back to the system(you can see that in the image, the functionality of minimizing and maximizing are still working at that place even though they aren't showing up when I log-back)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Firefox window is just positioned a bit higher up the screen than before, and is getting covered by the bar at the top.

I don't use that particular desktop environment, but it seems like you could just move the window a bit down, and see more of the top of it. Maybe you should reduce its vertical size a bit first, otherwise it would of course just move some of the bottom of the window out of sight.